# October Cms - can't see plugin

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, octobercms

I'm new to October. CMS is installed on web server, command shell is unaccessible.

I've created plugin using official documentation - folders, Plugin.php, required minimum. But CMS can't see this plugin, only plugins from the marketplace. What could be the reason?

Comment: First check permission for the plugin of the plugin

Comment: Could you share your exact directory structure of your plugin?

Answer (score 1):

1) In the plugins folder place a folder with the plugin author name. eg: 'custom' for this.

2) now create the folder with the plugin name. eg: 'product'
3) inside the plugin folder (product) create the Plugin.php file. with the following content.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Product;
use System\Classes\PluginBase;

/**
 * Product Plugin Information File
 */
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    /**
     * Returns information about this plugin.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function pluginDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'Product',
            'description' => 'Manage product section.',
            'author'      => 'Auther',
            'icon'        => 'icon-leaf'
        ];
    } 
}
```

3) this might not be a must-have but you can use it. Create a folder name 'updates' in the 'product' folder and place a file name version.yaml with the following content.

1.0.0: 
    - First version of product

4) now check in the back end. if you don't see the plugin in manage plugins section just **logout** and **login** and check again.

*Note: this is just the basic. You can use the builder plugin to create plugin easily as **Oleg Samorai** mentioned.*

Comment: If I remember correctly: logout / login triggers the installation of the newly added plugin.

Comment: Did you navigate to "Updates & Plugins" -> "manage plugins" to see if the new plugin in that section for you?

Answer (score 0):

did you have plugin.yaml file with correct settings in the root of your plugin folder ?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you don't add the `updates` folder to your plugin. So go ahead add that folder and make sure to include the `version.yaml` file.

Then run `php artisan october:up` and it should appear in your backend plugins table.

**If you don't have console access then just click on `Check for updates` > `Force update`**